# Proper way to inject custom configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, configuration, .net-core

The problem to solve:
There is a list of settings lets say:

```
{
   "Kind1":
     {"attr1":"val11"},
     {"attr2":"val12"},
   "Kind2":
     {"attr1":"val21"},
     {"attr2":"val22"},       
}
```

and a consumer class (controller) in .NET Core 2.1, needs to access the above configuration to use Kind1 or Kind2.

Supposing corresponding class is already defined in C#:

```
 public class KindSetting
 {
    public string attr1{get;set;}
    public string attr2{get;set;}
 }
```

Now what is the best way of inject the configuration into the consumer object.

Is there a way to inject an `IConfiguration` instance into the consumer object and use it like this?:

```
KindSetting kindSetting =_configuration.GetValue<KindSetting>(kindSettingKey);
```

Is there any better approach to fulfill the above requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following approach, although I am not sure it's the best, in the startup class `Configure` method:

```cs
services.Configure<List<KindSetting>>(Configuration.GetSection("KindSettingList"));
```

and in the consumer object side:

```cs
public ConsumerController(IOptions<List<KindSetting>> kindSettingsListAccessor, ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

In the startup.cs file, in the ConfigureServices method you can do a configuration. Sample code below:

```
   // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Need to add following lines
        services.Configure<KindSetting>(Configuration.GetSection("Kind1"));
     }
```

After adding into services, you can inject this configuration in your class, like follow:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private readonly IOptions<KindSetting> _KindSetting;
    
    public HomeController(IOptions<KindSetting> KindSetting)
    {
        _KindSetting = KindSetting
    }
    
    public void myFunction()
    {
            var mysetting = _KindSetting.Value.attr1
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be decided about "Kind1" or "Kind2" inside the class which need to receive the whole configurations related to KindSetting.

Answer (score -2):

After adding `services.Configure<KindSettings>`, you can inject configuration via DI by adding to your constructor.

```
IOptionsSnapshot<KindSettings> kindSettingsConfiguration
```

or

```
IOptions<KindSettings> kindSettingsConfiguration
```

The difference is, `IOptionsSnapshot` will reflect live changes in your config file, while `IOptions` is for singleton use.

Edit after comment:

Lets say your configuration file looks like this:

```
{
  "Kind1":
    {"attr1":"val11"},
    {"attr2":"val12"},
  "Kind2":
    {"attr1":"val21"},
    {"attr2":"val22"},       
}
```

To successfully bind this, you would need two configuration classes

```
public class Kind1Configuration
{
    public string Attr1 { get; set; }
    public string Attr2 { get; set; }
}

public class Kind2Configuration
{
    public string Attr1 { get; set; }
    public string Attr2 { get; set; }
}
```

And as previously stated, to connect the dots just add

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<Kind1Configuration>(Configuration.GetSection("Kind1"));

    services.Configure<Kind2Configuration>(Configuration.GetSection("Kind2"));
}
```

To use this in a controller, add your IOptions to the constructor

```
public class TestController(IOptionsSnapshot<Kind1Configuration> kindSettingsConfiguration)
{
    Kind1Configuration configuration = kindSettingsConfiguration.Value;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What do you mean by KindSettings? list of KindSetting? I want to pass a part of configuration to the object.

Comment: You didn't fully show how to use IOptions in ConfigureServices or in Controller.

Comment: Could you please give an explanation before downvoting.